# Alternating sum of length of homologies of chain complexes of modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, exact-sequence, abelian-categories, additive-categories

Let $R$ be a Commutative Noetherian ring. For a chain complex $A_*$ of finitely generated $R$-modules which is homologically finite (i.e. only finitely many homologies $H_i(A_*)$ are non-zero) and each Homology has finite length as an $R$-module, define $\chi(A_*):=\sum_i (-1)^i l(H_i(A_*))$ , where $l(-)$ denotes length of a module.

So now let $0\to A_*\to B_*\to C_*\to 0$ be a short exact sequence of homologically finite chain complexes of finitely generated $R$-modules such that each of the complexes have finite length homologies.

Then, is it true that $\chi(B_*)=\chi(A_*)+\chi(C_*)$ ?

I think I have to use the induced Long exact sequence of the homologies of the complexes and use that length is alternating on a Long exact sequence, but I'm having trouble writing down a rigorous proof.

Please help

Comment: Do you mean $\chi(A_*):=\sum_i (-1)^i l(H_i(A_*))$? Then simply write the long exact sequence, write the alternating sum of the lengths, and you'll obtain  $\chi(A_*)- \chi(B_*)+ \chi(C_*)=0$.

Comment: It's more usual to define Euler characteristic as $\sum_i(-1)^i\ell(H_i(A))$.

Comment: Yes, you will have trouble if you do not take the alternating sum, as the claim is then not true.

Comment: @A.G.: I did mean alternating sum, thanks